# Using docker-compose to interpolate variables in a file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using Portainer to manage containers on a host, and one of the things Portainer does is environment variable management. It's pretty convenient to add variables in its web UI.

I can use these variables in the `docker-compose.yml` "stack" of Portainer, but it would be really convenient if I could interpolate variables into files in the deployed containers.

What occured to me is that I could use `command` to do it one by one, e.g.:

```
service:
 image: foo
 command: "sed -i 's/SOME_VAR/$SOME_VAR/g' /etc/config.txt"
 command: "sed -i 's/ANOTHER_VAR/$ANOTHER_VAR/g' /etc/config.txt"
```

But that would mean doing it manually for every variable, it would be pretty unsafe just dropping variables into sed like that, especially paths, and there's about a dozen of them.

Is there something which would do it in bulk, and more sefely?

Comment: This won't work in any case; you can't have multiple `command` entries for a service, and setting `command` like this would override the default behavior of the service such that it would no longer work.

Comment: I see it now in the docs :(

Comment: If your image is built on the GNU toolset (a Debian or Ubuntu image base typically) then it has an envsubst(1) tool that an entrypoint wrapper script could run.